# navigator.globalization.getLocaleName not running on PhoneGap 2.2.0

Tags: ios, cordova, globalization

Using PhoneGap 2.2.0, which includes Globalization in the core now, I am calling the `navigator.globalization.getLocaleName()` function on iOS but it doesn't seem to run. Here's my code:

```js
$('#home').bind('pageshow', function()
{
    navigator.globalization.getLocaleName(function(locale)
    {
        alert('locale: '+locale.value);
    },
    function(error)
    {
        alert('error occured: '+error);
    });
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same issue. Did you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should put it inside the deviceready event like this:

```
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
            navigator.globalization.getLocaleName(function(locale)

 {
        alert('locale: '+locale.value);
    },
    function(error)
    {
        alert('error occured: '+error);
}

}
```